# Как скопировать лист из excel в word , но на формат страницы А3?

Tags: excel, vba

Есть код,который копирует таблицы из excel  в word. Но эти таблицы очень большие. как сделать так,чтобы в ворд копировалось сразу на формат А3?

```
Sub Word()
Dim WrdApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
If WrdApp Is Nothing Then
Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
WrdApp.Visible = True
End If
WrdDoc.SaveAs Filename:="D:\1.doc", FileFormat:=6
Range("A1:CC141").Copy
WrdDoc.Range(0).Paste
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

End Sub
```

Comment: *как сделать так,чтобы в ворд копировалось сразу на формат А3?* Никак. Содержимое документа и формат раздела не связаны вообще никак. Отдельно - копируете контент, отдельно - устанавливаете нужный формат. Впрочем, лучше в обратном порядке...

Comment: @Akina если ли какие свойства,чтобы подогнать под размер экрана таблицу? я нашла такое свойство Set WordTable = WordDoc.Tables(1);WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow) ....но у меня не работает

Comment: Не... всё руками, руками... вот что можно сделать руками - наклацать в менюшке, натыкать мышом,- то можно и программно. Макрорекордер в помощь. Ну а чего нет, того нет. Таблица-то по границам автоматически никак не выравнивается, так что берёшь размеры страницы, размеры таблицы - и подгоняй.